# Проблема с фильтром OpenCart 3.0.2 при переезде на ssl

Tags: opencart, https

Когда поставил сертификат https на сайт, который стоит на open cart, и поставил переадресацию, то перестал работать фильтр товаров.

В консоли ошибок такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поскажите что сделать чтобы не было этого?

Comment: у вас где-то заброс посылается на HTTP, найдите это место и исправьте на HTTPS

Answer (score 2):

Просто поставить переадресацию недостаточно.

"Система" - "Настройки" - "Сервер" - Использовать SSL **Включить**

Открыть `config.php` и `admin/config.php` и вот в эти строки добавить `https`

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'https://example.com/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://example.com/');
```

Comment: Спасибо. Проблемма решилась но непонятно каким образом.
Сейчас распишу сверху.

Answer (score -1):

Проблемма решилась но я так и не понял как.
переставил сертификат назад на http 
в файлах config.php и admin/config.php  я поменял значения на http
После этого в настройках поменял checkbox "включить ssl" на "нет"
Сейчас ВНИМАНИЕ
В итоге настройки в файлах 
config.php и admin/config.php поменял на https и в файле .htaccess  стоит переадресация
НО в меню "включить ssl" стои на НЕТ!
И все работает. 
Странно но так как есть.
Если у кого то есть соображения из чего такое стало то напишите.

Comment: вполне может быть, в настройках не обязательно ставить ssl. Бывает и без него работает.